# POST request need to return html page

Tags: javascript, python, django, bottle

Im using a Bottle framework but it will be relevant to any Python frameworks or web development...

I have a button id=exportLink, when its clicked I post a request to the server using the below command...The server will process the request and will generate a html page...

Problem:-

When its get request the html page is rendered properly but when its a post request the HTML page is not rendered but the html contents are returned to my request...

Requirement:-
My post requests should display the webpage and should not return the html content...

GET request

```
    window.open("./SimpleHTML?portfolio=no&antiCSRF={{acs}}&session_id={{session}}&targetpage=main"&search_string="+search)
```

POST request

```
 $('#exportLink1').click(function(e){
        var search = $('#small_search_string').val();
        $.post("SimpleHTML",
             { search_string: search,
                     antiCSRF: '{{acs}}',
                     session_id: '{{session}}',
                     targetpage: 'main',
                     searchstring: search,
             }
            ).fail(function() { alert("The search failed."); });


   })
```

POST request results:

```
<h3 style= 'display:inline'>Price</h3>
<p style='display:inline'>2</p><br />
<h3 style= 'display:inline'>Full Price: </h3>
<p style='display:inline'>10</p>
```

GET request results:

HTML page with above content is rendered properly...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just insert returned data into the current page, say into `#results` div:

```
$('#exportLink1').click(function(e) {
    var search = $('#small_search_string').val();
    $.post("SimpleHTML", { 
        search_string: search,
        // ...
    })
    .fail(function() { alert("The search failed."); })
    .done(function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
    });
});
```